# libhdf5.so.200, needed by /opt/opencv3/lib/libopencv_hdf.so, not found

Tags: linux, c++, qt, opencv

I developing C++ application with Qt&OpenCV. Last week i was building my application without any error but now I got the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libhdf5.so.200, needed by /opt/opencv3/lib/libopencv_hdf.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/opencv3/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5Dread'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/opencv3/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5Fcreate'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/opencv3/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5T_NATIVE_UCHAR_g'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/opencv3/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5Tget_size'
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/opencv3/lib/libopencv_hdf.so: undefined reference to `H5check_version'
... (hdf5 related errors)
```

Im using arch linux, Im not sure if this error related to last updates. But, in `/opt/opencv3/lib` dir, I have this:

```
ll | grep hdf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       20 Feb  7 13:08 libopencv_hdf.so -> libopencv_hdf.so.3.4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       23 Feb  7 13:08 libopencv_hdf.so.3.4 -> libopencv_hdf.so.3.4.19
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    55144 Feb  7 13:08 libopencv_hdf.so.3.4.19
```

So `libopencv_hdf.so` linked to `libopencv_hdf.so.3.4.19` and it exists there. But why my build says `libopencv_hdf.so` needs `libhdf5.so.200`?

I am using `opencv3-opt` package from AUR. Any idea to resolve problem?

Comment: **Very likely** related to your last update. remove your build directory, run cmake/qmake/whatever makefile generator you use again, and see whether the error goes away.

Comment: I did this, clean, run qmake and build again but still same error.

Comment: then you have some qmake cache somewhere, because what we're seeing here tells us that your compiler thinks that there are functions defined in some header that your linker can't find; this should have failed at the compilation stage, not the linking stage, so either your compiler is using headers that don't match the libraries, or you're trying to link object files that are actually from the old build. Make sure your AUR is also compatible with your current build.

Comment: So which hdf5 package do you have installed? The [current arch package of hdf5](https://archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/hdf5/) contains `libhdf5.so.310`, so if `opencv` requires the old version, you have to install that.

Comment: I think @MarcusMüller was right but i cant understand how. Yes I have hdf5 installed. I am compiling my program with using ```pkg-config opencv```. In opencv.pc file, i removed ```-lopencv_hdf``` from libs, compiled again and it worked without error. After that, i added ```-lopencv_hdf``` and compiled again and still there is no problem. I dont know how and why. I have latest hdf5 by the way